# Laravel Eloquent join several tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

```
products
|id|name|about|

=categories=
|id|name|parent|

=products-categories=
|id|product_id|cat_id|
```

I need to take a product categories names. I have a sql query:

```
SELECT s.name FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN `products-categories` AS cats ON p.id = cats.product_id
LEFT JOIN `categories` AS s ON cats.cat_id = s.id 
WHERE product_id = 1;
```

And It works! But how I can do this with the help of Laravel Eloquent (Not Fluent!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Eloquent` relationship and in this case, create two models, for both tables, i.e. `product` and `Category`:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'categories'; // optional

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'products_categories', 'category_id', 'product_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'products'; // optional

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'products_categories', 'product_id', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

Now you may use these relationship methods to get related data, for example:

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->find(1);
```

This will return the product with id `1` and all the related categories in a collection so you may use `$product->categories->first()->name` or you may do a loop on the categories like:

```
foreach($product->categories as $cat) {
    echo $cat->name;
}
```

Also you may use `join` which doesn't require the relationship methods and you may use same approach to join the models that is used in `Fluent` (Check other answer). But either way, you need to store the `category` and `product` mappings in the `products_categories` table. Read more about `many-to-many` relationship on `Laravel` [website](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `leftJoin` method. It works the same in Eloquent as in Query Builder.

```
$product = Product::leftJoin('product-categories', 'product-categories.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'product-categories.cat_id')
->where('product_id', 1)
->first(['categories.name']);
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems OP intention was not to use the Fluent builder.